# Adding a directory globally to cffi:*foreign-library-directories*

Tags: common-lisp, cffi

I am using the Nix package manager under macOS to install much of my software, including dynamic libraries. And I would like to make them accessible to CFFI. That means adding a path to `cffi:*foreign-library-directories*`. Fine, but how can I do this

- globally for my system (should work for packages loaded via Quicklisp, for example)
- without loading CFFI every time I start `sbcl`?

Ignoring the second criterion, I can just add a few lines to `~/.sbclrc`:

```
(ql:quickload "CFFI")
(pushnew (merge-pathnames ".nix-profile/lib/" (user-homedir-pathname))
         cffi:*foreign-library-directories*
         :test #'equal)
```

What I am looking for is a way to add the path *after* CFFI is loaded. A bit like `eval-after-load` in Emacs Lisp. Is that possible?

Comment: I am not too familiar with nix, but maybe loading sbcl with nix-env could setup the environment so that the underlying dlopen calls works transparently?

Comment: I do install sbcl via nix, but that's just plain sbcl. Nix (at least for macOS) doesn't seem to contain any Lisp libraries packaged for sbcl. There are many packages whose names start with `lisp-` though, but there are also other Lisp implementations.

Comment: Note however that Nix is not the core issue here. I also have libraries installed using Homebrew under `/opt/brew`, which leads to the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should try to use the mechanisms of the underlying system instead, i. e. on Linux `ldconfig` (resp. `ld.so.conf`), on MacOS `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  The CFFI manual says that the `*foreign-library-directories*` are only used as a fallback if the system mechanism fails.

Comment: The CFFI manual does not mention that environment variables are honored, but at least under SBCL/macOS, this does work. Since it is easy to mess up a macOS system by setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I decided to do so only in `.sbclrc`: `(setf (uiop/os:getenv "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH")
      (uiop:strcat (uiop/os:getenv "HOME")
                   "/" ".nix-profile/lib/"))`